# KnockOutJS to add two textbox values together

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

All I'm trying to do is to get KnockOut to add the value of two text boxes together, and put the result into the third.

I have a JSFiddle here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qzjh6/)

My HTML boxes are:

```
<input data-bind="value:AirportPickup" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Airport Pickup £10 per person must be a number." data-val-required="The Airport Pickup £10 per person field is required." id="AirportPickup" name="AirportPickup" type="text" value="0" />

<input data-bind="value:PackedLunch" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Packed Lunch £6.50 must be a number." data-val-required="The Packed Lunch £6.50 field is required." id="PackedLunch" name="PackedLunch" type="text" value="0" />

<input data-bind="value:Breakfast" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Breakfast £6.00 must be a number." data-val-required="The Breakfast £6.00 field is required." id="Breakfast" name="Breakfast" type="text" value="0" />
```

...and my jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function AppViewModel() {
    this.AirportPickup = ko.observable("");
    this.PackedLunch = ko.observable("");
    this.Breakfast = AirportPickup + PackedLunch;
}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
```

Nothing happens though, when I put anything into the first two textboxes.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html):

http://jsfiddle.net/7kQP6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function AppViewModel() {
        this.AirportPickup = ko.observable(0);
        this.PackedLunch = ko.observable(0);
        this.Breakfast = ko.computed(function () {
            return Number(this.AirportPickup()) + Number(this.PackedLunch())
        }, this);
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
```

Note that this code needs some validation (make sure the input is a number, for example).

Answer (score 2):

Another way could be

http://jsfiddle.net/7kQP6/1/

Just set the value in the data-bind

```
 <input data-bind="value:AirportPickup" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Airport Pickup £10 per person must be a number." data-val-required="The Airport Pickup £10 per person field is required." id="AirportPickup" name="AirportPickup" type="text" value="0" />

<input data-bind="value:PackedLunch" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Packed Lunch £6.50 must be a number." data-val-required="The Packed Lunch £6.50 field is required." id="PackedLunch" name="PackedLunch" type="text" value="0" />

<input data-bind="value:Number(AirportPickup()) + Number( PackedLunch())" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Breakfast £6.00 must be a number." data-val-required="The Breakfast £6.00 field is required." id="Breakfast" name="Breakfast" type="text" value="0" />;
```

Answer (score 1):

this.Breakfast needs to be a computed observable:

```
this.Breakfast = ko.computed(function() {
 return this.AirportPickup + this.PackedLunch;
});
```